# Problem with JSON encoded string from "kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I implemented the laravel extension https://github.com/kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue and after long debugging I found the error why it's not working.
The extension uses the lang.js. And in lang.js is the message formed like this:
**Listing 1:**

```
{
    messages: {
        'en.greetings': {
            'hi': 'Hi',
            'hello': 'Hello'
        },
        'it.greetings': {
            'hi': 'Salve'
        }
    }
}
```

The `kg-bot/laravel-localization-to-vue` extension create this JSON 
**Listing 2:**

```
{"en":{"auth":{"failed":"These credentials do not match our records.","throttle":"Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds."},"messages":{"Hello":"Hello Welt"},"pagination":{"previous":"\u0026laquo; Previous","next":"Next \u0026raquo;"},"passwords":{"password":"Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation.","reset":"Your password has been reset!","sent":"We have e-mailed your password reset link!","token":"This password reset token is invalid.","user":"We can\u0027t find a user with that e-mail address."},"validation":{"accepted":"The :attribute must be accepted.","active_url":"The :attribute is not a valid URL.","after":"The :attribute must be a date after :date.","after_or_equal":"The :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.","alpha":"The :attribute may only contain letters.","alpha_dash":"The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, dashes and underscores.","alpha_num":"The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.","array":"The :attribute must be an array.","before":"The :attribute must be a date before :date.","before_or_equal":"The :attribute must be a date before or equal to :date.","between":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max.","file":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.","array":"The :attribute must have between :min and :max items."},"boolean":"The :attribute field must be true or false.","confirmed":"The :attribute confirmation does not match.","date":"The :attribute is not a valid date.","date_equals":"The :attribute must be a date equal to :date.","date_format":"The :attribute does not match the format :format.","different":"The :attribute and :other must be different.","digits":"The :attribute must be :digits digits.","digits_between":"The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.","dimensions":"The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.","distinct":"The :attribute field has a duplicate value.","email":"The :attribute must be a valid email address.","ends_with":"The :attribute must end with one of the following: :values","exists":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","file":"The :attribute must be a file.","filled":"The :attribute field must have a value.","gt":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be greater than :value.","file":"The :attribute must be greater than :value kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be greater than :value characters.","array":"The :attribute must have more than :value items."},"gte":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value.","file":"The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be greater than or equal :value characters.","array":"The :attribute must have :value items or more."},"image":"The :attribute must be an image.","in":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","in_array":"The :attribute field does not exist in :other.","integer":"The :attribute must be an integer.","ip":"The :attribute must be a valid IP address.","ipv4":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv4 address.","ipv6":"The :attribute must be a valid IPv6 address.","json":"The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.","lt":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be less than :value.","file":"The :attribute must be less than :value kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be less than :value characters.","array":"The :attribute must have less than :value items."},"lte":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be less than or equal :value.","file":"The :attribute must be less than or equal :value kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be less than or equal :value characters.","array":"The :attribute must not have more than :value items."},"max":{"numeric":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max.","file":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.","array":"The :attribute may not have more than :max items."},"mimes":"The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.","mimetypes":"The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.","min":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be at least :min.","file":"The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be at least :min characters.","array":"The :attribute must have at least :min items."},"not_in":"The selected :attribute is invalid.","not_regex":"The :attribute format is invalid.","numeric":"The :attribute must be a number.","present":"The :attribute field must be present.","regex":"The :attribute format is invalid.","required":"The :attribute field is required.","required_if":"The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.","required_unless":"The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.","required_with":"The :attribute field is required when :values is present.","required_with_all":"The :attribute field is required when :values are present.","required_without":"The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.","required_without_all":"The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.","same":"The :attribute and :other must match.","size":{"numeric":"The :attribute must be :size.","file":"The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.","string":"The :attribute must be :size characters.","array":"The :attribute must contain :size items."},"starts_with":"The :attribute must start with one of the following: :values","string":"The :attribute must be a string.","timezone":"The :attribute must be a valid zone.","unique":"The :attribute has already been taken.","uploaded":"The :attribute failed to upload.","url":"The :attribute format is invalid.","uuid":"The :attribute must be a valid UUID.","custom":{"attribute-name":{"rule-name":"custom-message"}},"attributes":[]}}};
```

JSON data listing 1 is working. Listing 2 not. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem.
I patched `vendor\kg-bot\laravel-localization-to-vue\src\Classes\ExportLocalizations.php` and replaced

```
// Check if language already exists in array
if (array_key_exists($language, $this->strings)) {
    if (array_key_exists($packageName, $this->strings[$language.'.'.$packageName])) {
        $this->strings[$language.'.'.$packageName] =
            array_replace_recursive((array) $this->strings[$language.'.'.$packageName], (array)
            $fileContents);
    } else {
        $this->strings[$language.'.'.$packageName] = $fileContents;
    }
} else {
    $this->strings[$language] = [
        $packageName => $fileContents,
    ];
}
```

with

```
$this->strings[$language.'.'.$packageName] = $fileContents;
```

now the json is correct formed for lang.js